# How to remove Android Lint warning related to sourceSets

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I'm trying to remove the last Lint warning from my Android Project. I'm using the latest IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.

The warning is:

```
    'sourceSets' cannot be applied to
 '(groovy.lang.Closure<com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet>)' (at line 28)
```

I've seen multiple questions on SO where `cannot be applied to "XXXX"` is something else than AndroidSourceSet and the suggested solution did not apply to my problem.

My version of Android Gradle Plugin is the latest : 1.5.0

Here is my sourceSets, located in the android section of my gradle file.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('src/test/java')
}
```

When I'm checking the gradle documentation, I can't see what's wrong with this. I'm about to suppress the inspection for this statement but I want to be sure that it's ok.

Thanks.

***EDIT***

Here is the full gradle file (with some info removed for privacy).

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
          mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: 'versionupdate.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test/java')
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        pickFirst 'LICENSE.txt'
        return true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        Signing {
            keyAlias 'somekey'
            keyPassword 'key'
            storeFile file('../.keystore')
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }

    buildTypes {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = file("$project.buildDir/outputs/apk/myprogram.apk")
            }
        }

        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-SNAPSHOT"
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Signing
        }
        release {
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Signing
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    return true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.4'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    compile 'net.erdfelt.android:apk-parser:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.9'
    compile 'com.fatboyindustrial.gson-jodatime-serialisers:gson-jodatime-serialisers:1.2.0'
    compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0'
}
```

Comment: what's at line 28?

Comment: The first line: sourceSets {

Answer (score 0):

Your `sourceSets` block seems to be at the wrong place. Make sure it is directly inside `android` block at the same level as `buildTypes` and `defaultConfig`.

Also, looking at your code you dont need the sourceSets block at all. Everything is set to default.

Comment: It is directly inside android block. As far as I know, my project is not the default. It has the default path of a Eclipse project, which is very different from IntelliJ/Android Studio structure. That's why I use the sourceSets block :)

Comment: Ah you are right... Can you share full gradle file?

Comment: Put the sourceSets below buildtypes

Comment: it doesn't change anything. Start to smell like a bug in the Lint validation for gradle...

Comment: did you try invalidate cache and restart. Most of the things people are clueless about somehow vanishes after doing that.

Comment: if you are talking about gradle cache, I've deleted the entire directory but nothing changed...